python 3.10 doesn't let me use df.dt python 3.9 is ok
Showing a minimalist example below, I essentially have two functions, one to create a year column using "Date" column as input, and the other function which loads the data into a df from a csv file.
def create_year_column(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year.astype(str)
    return df

def load_data(path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # load the data from csv file
    data = pd.read_csv(
        path,
        dtype={
            'amount': float,
            'category': str,
            'date': str,
        },
        parse_dates=['date']
    )

    create_year_column(data)

    return data

The problem I have is that when I run this in python 3.10 I get the following error:

AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values. Did you mean: 'at'?

It seems to have issues with the line of code where I use:
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year.astype(str)

I technically assume that the df['date'] column is allready parsed as a date format, which it is since its called in the load_data() function after I format it as such (using: parse_dates=['date'] ).
When I run this code in pyton 3.9 I have no issues, only 3.10 is giving me heartache. Anyone know why?

What does print(pd.__version__) show on Python 3.9 and 3.10? It would also help if your example was reproducible.

Could you please print(data.dtypes) before the create_year_column(data) call and share the result?

You've explicitly declared your date column as str so I guess I'm not surprised.

You might want to try manually converting your date string to a Pandas DateTime.
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"])
create_year_column(data)

It's possible that depending on the format of your date it not's automatically parsing it as a date. I ended up in a situation where I had to be pretty explict to get my dates to work. e.g.:
data["date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["date"], format='ISO8601', dayfirst=False)

Check out the documentation for to_datetime here.
